# Getting and saving value from POST with nested serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
class InfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = EventInfo
        fields = ('email', 'pin')

class EventSerializer(DataSerializer, GeoModelAPIView):
    # other fields
    event_info = InfoSerializer(read_only=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        event_info = validated_data.pop('event_info', {})
        event = super().create(validated_data)
        EventInfo.objects.create(event=event, **event_info)
        return event
```

Model

```
class EventInfo(models.Model):
    pin = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField()
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
```

POST

```
{
    # other data
    "event_info": {
        "email": "example@example.com",
        "pin": "1234567890"
    }
}
```

So I have a model that is not visible on the browsable API, but I want to be able to save data from POST request to that model. Using this code I can create the objects and it correctly links the info to a correct Event model. However the email and pin fields won't get saved. What I have figured out is that the 'event_info' data from the POST is not visible on the validated_data.

The validation goes to the DataSerializer's validation method but I guess that I should somehow bypass the validation for just the 'event_info' data?

**Edit:**

```
class EventViewSet(BulkModelViewSet, JSONAPIViewSet):
    queryset = Event.objects.filter(deleted=False)
    queryset = queryset.select_related('location')
    queryset = queryset.prefetch_related(list of related fields)
    serializer_class = EventSerializer
    filter_backends = (EventOrderingFilter, filters.DjangoFilterBackend)
    filter_class = EventFilter
    ordering_fields = (fields to order by)
    ordering = ('-last_modified_time',)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def initial(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super().initial(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super(EventViewSet, self).get_serializer_context()
        context.setdefault('skip_fields', set()).update(set([
        'headline',
        'secondary_headline']))
        return context


    @atomic
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        if isinstance(serializer.validated_data, list):
        event_data_list = serializer.validated_data
        else:
            event_data_list = [serializer.validated_data]

        super().perform_create(serializer)
```

Comment: change `event_info = InfoSerializer(read_only=True)` to `event_info = InfoSerializer()`

Comment: Doing so produces the following error `Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `event_info` on serializer `EventSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Event` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Event' object has no attribute 'event_info'.`

Comment: can you add your `view` as well ?

Comment: For what purpose you inherited `GeoModelAPIView` into a `Serializer` class ?

Comment: This is a already made software that I'm modifying to add more functionality. So I'm not entirely sure why parts of it are made the way it is made.

Comment: Ok then, change `event_info` to `event` in POST DATA

Comment: If I don't have the read_only set to true, I can't even view the GET, and when POSTing, I get the same attribute error. In the POST the name has to be same as it is set on the serializer.